# How can I copy a directory without copying a specific file or subdirectory in terminal?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, cp

I have a directory main_dir which contains lots of files and 3 subdirectories (dir1 and dir2 and dir3). I want to copy it to another location without copying dir2 in one command. I searched the cp manual to see if this can be done somehow but I did not find the answer. 
My only solution was to copy the whole directory and then delete dir2 in the copied location.

```
cp -r main_dir ~/Documents/main_dir_copy
cd ~/Documents/main_dir_copy
rm -r dir2
```

Is there a way to do this without having to copy all the contents of dir2 and then delete it?

Comment: rsynch has an exclude option ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In bash, you can use an *extended glob* to implement negation.

Given

```
$ tree main_dir
main_dir
├── dir1
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
├── dir2
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
├── dir3
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
└── file

3 directories, 7 files
```

then

```
shopt -s extglob
cp -r main_dir/!(dir2) main_dir_copy/
```

resulting in

```
$ tree main_dir_copy
main_dir_copy
├── dir1
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
├── dir3
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
└── file

2 directories, 5 files
```

Note that since this recursively copies the *contents* of `main_dir` (excluding the given `dir2`) rather than `main_dir` itself, the target directory `main_dir_copy` must already exist - if it doesn't, add `mkdir main_dir_copy` to the command sequence.

See also

- [How to exclude some files from filename expansion mechanism in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335484/how-to-exclude-some-files-from-filename-expansion-mechanism-in-bash)
- [Delete subdirectories leaving a given one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/377963/delete-subdirectories-leaving-a-given-one)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. (Note: I had to create the directory first with mkdir to work. Previously the cp created the directory on it's own.)

Comment: @GaálDániel thanks - I have edited the answer to mention the need for the target directory to exist. Apologies for not making that clear.